# Multiple Counts in one Query with left joins - what to group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I can quite happily run this code with one count in it:

```
select 
  count(`reprint`.`user_id`) as `reprintcount`, 
  `users`.`email` as `email`,
  `users`.`type` as `type`
from `users`
left join `reprint`
  on `users`.`id` = `reprint`.`user_id`
where `users`.`type` = 'assistant' 
  or `users`.`type` = 'admin' 
  or `users`.`type` = 'supervisor'
group by `users`.`id`
```

And I'll get something like this:

```
+--------------+-------------------+------------+
| reprintcount |       email       |    type    |
+--------------+-------------------+------------+
|            8 | user1@example.org | admin      |
|            0 | user2example.org  | supervisor |
+--------------+-------------------+------------+
```

But I start getting issues when I add in another table via a left join and throw in another count.

```
select 
  count(`checkin`.`user_id`) as `printcount`, 
  count(`reprint`.`user_id`) as `reprint`, 
  `users`.`email` as `email`,
  `users`.`type` as `type`
from `users` 
left join `checkin` 
  on `users`.`id` = `checkin`.`user_id`
left join `reprint`
  on `users`.`id` = `reprint`.`user_id`
where `users`.`type` = 'assistant' 
  or `users`.`type` = 'admin' 
  or `users`.`type` = 'supervisor'
group by `users`.`id`
```

The issue I'm getting is that I'm getting unexpected numbers from the counts. I've tried grouping by user.id, checkin.user_id, reprin`.user_id or a mix of the three but to no avail. This is what I get:

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+------------+
| checkincount | reprintcount |       email       |    type    |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+------------+
|           32 |           32 | user1@example.org | admin      |
|            1 |            0 | user2@example.org | supervisor |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+------------+
```

This is what I'm expecting:

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+------------+
| checkincount | reprintcount |       email       |    type    |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+------------+
|            4 |            8 | user1@example.org | admin      |
|            1 |            0 | user2@example.org | supervisor |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+------------+
```

Any direction on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated. I could of course do this is two separate queries but I'm trying to avoid that so the page will load faster and I'm guessing this can be done in one query? Thanks!

Comment: try count(distinct ...) - although subqueries or a derived table will probably be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  c.`printcount`, 
  r.`reprint`, 
  `users`.`email` as `email`,
  `users`.`type` as `type`
from `users` 
left join (
   select `user_id`, count(*) as `printcount`
   from `checkin` 
   group by `user_id`
) as c
  on `users`.`id` = c.`user_id`
left join (
   select `user_id`, count(*) as `reprint`
   from `reprint` 
   group by `user_id`
) as r
  on `users`.`id` = r.`user_id`
where `users`.`type` = 'assistant' 
  or `users`.`type` = 'admin' 
  or `users`.`type` = 'supervisor'
```

Comment: I have no information about the structure, but yes you are right we can remove that group

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Alex - I can see what I was doing wrong now!